# How to put the price and the "add-to-cart button" below each other with css. Using the shortcode [add_to_cart id='id-no']

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding a Add-To-Cart button on a random page in my woocommerce shop using the shortcode on the back-end `[add_to_cart id='product-no' class='' style='']`

The text in my column is centered, so putting the price and the buy button below each other looks better.

How do I get a line break (or "clear") between the price and the button on the front-end?

$39
Add to cart

Help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell you seem to have two elements [Price] and [Button] next to each other:

```
[Price] [Button]
```

You could try add a `</br>` tag:

```
[Price] </br> [Button]
```

If adding a `</br>` doesn't put it on a new line you could try some CSS.

Change the width of [Price] or [Button]:

```
.ELEMENT {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or use Flex:

```
<div class="flex-column">
    [Price] [Button]
</div>
```

```
.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Or change the display attribute of the [Price] or [Button] element in CSS:

```
.ELEMENT {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks, man... display: block worked in this scenario... after changing the width I also had to set margin right and left to auto... so it stayed centered as well...